# java decompiler with save line numbers in actual physical position for intellij-idea

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, decompiling, decompiler

Many IDE's debugger match the physical line number. I'm looking for java decompiler with saving actual line number in decompiling code for intellij-idea .

Comment: I'm not sure, but I thought JD-GUI did the trick nicely.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux it does not - eclipse for example requires that another plugin such as the following http://sourceforge.net/projects/realignmentjd/files/ be installed over the JD-Eclipse plugin

Answer (score 0):

i think that Java Decompiler from http://jd.benow.ca/ does it in the `jd-gui` version

Add a nosense example with line numbers, 5 lines between two lines and 8 difference in the line number...

Sorry for my english and so bad explanation....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/) supports this as an experimental feature, but there is no IntelliJ integration at the moment.  You would have to run it from the command line and add source directory mappings in IntelliJ.

To enable this feature, run with `-sl` or `--stretch-lines`.  You must also run with `-o` to save the output to `.java` files instead of printing to the console.